# How to add "Allowed Countries" field in custom form

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I need to create a custom module which allows admin to create Zones for different countries. I need to add 'allow country' field (just like in default magento `System > Configuration > General > Countries Options`) in my form where admin can select the countries for a zone.

I Just need to add a countries multi select field in my custom module admin form.

Can anyone help me how to do this. Thanks..

Comment: sorry forgot to ask, you wanna add this in your custom config section or admin form?

Comment: I need to add the field in my custom module admin form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.
To add a country multi select dropdown in your form you need to add below code in your `Block/Adminhtml/ModuleName/Edit/Tab/Form.php` file.

```
$countryList = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(true);
$fieldset->addField('countries', 'multiselect', array(
            'name'      => 'countries[]',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('zones')->__('Countries'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('zones')->__('Countries'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => $countryList,
        ));
```

Answer (score 6):

> To bring in the allowed countries field in your custom module config:

add the following to your module's **system.xml**

```
<sallowspecific translate="label">
    <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>90</sort_order>
    <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</sallowspecific>
<specificcountry translate="label">
    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>91</sort_order>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
</specificcountry>
```

under `<fields>` tag in your custom section.

> To add it in the admin form:

in app/code/local/Yourmodulename/Block/Adminhtml/Yourmodulename/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
$countryList = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(true);
$fieldset->addField('allowed_countries', 'multiselect', array( /* "allowed_countries" is the column name in your custom table to store these values */
    'name'      => 'countries[]',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('yourmodulename')->__('Allowed Countries'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('yourmodulename')->__('Allowed Countries'),
    'required'  => true, /* only if it is required */
    'values'    => $countryList,
));
```

> note:
>
> - You have to write logic to save the multiselect values in database in saveAction()

to display this in admin grid:

refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606735/magento-insert-and-filter-multi-select-values-in-custom-admin-grid-module).

Comment: To save the multiselect values you just need to implode the post data using "," (eg. $countries = implode(",",$selectedCountries)) and save it in database. Magento will do everything else to get it back on edit or view page.

Answer (score 3):

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'select', array(  
        'name' => 'country',  
        'label' => 'Country',  
        'values' => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')->toOptionArray(),  
        ));
```